# How to publish findbugs report in jenkins using pipeline plugin?

Tags: jenkins, findbugs, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have gradle project and I add findbugs step. XML file with report is generated, but I have no idea how to display results in jenkins using pipeline plugin.

I installed findbugs plugin, but I don't find instructions how to use it in pipeline script.

How to use findbugs plugin in pipeline or where is documentation how to use findbugs in pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on official [FindBugs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FindBugs+Plugin) page recent release added support for Pipeline job :

> Release 4.62
>
> ```
> Added support for workflow plug-in (Thanks to Antonio Muñiz and Manuel Recena for their PRs)
> Fixed links in detail page of trend reports (JENKINS-29900)
> ```

You should be able to find FindBugs `step` in **Snippet Generator**, ie:

```
step([$class: 'FindBugsPublisher ', ... ])
```